# JSON.parse error with dollar in key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to parse the string `"{$Duration:1200,$Opacity:2}"` to Object

```
var tr = "{$Duration:1200,$Opacity:2}";
JSON.parse(tr);
```

fails with the exception

```
Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 1.
```

Any pointers on how should I handle this scenario?

Comment: They should be wrapped between `"`'s

Comment: This is not a valid JSON

Comment: Where do you get this "JSON" string from?

Comment: I am working jssor sliders and trying to use different transitions. Different transitions have different strings.
http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

Answer (score 2):

Object keys and strings need to be within double quotes in JSON.

Try this.

```
JSON.parse('{ "$Duration": 1200, "$Opacity": 2 }');
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them into `""`. This is a `JSON syntax`, wrap each key and value into `""`.You can put numbers and boolean values without `""`.

```js
var str = JSON.parse('{"$Duration":"1200","$Opacity":"2"}'); 
console.log(str);
```

Comment: `1200` and `2` need not be quoted. They will be parsed as numbers.

Comment: The string is the input. Is there easy way to modify the string as mentioned above

Comment: If it is an input string, why you need to parse it from json.?

Comment: The destination accepts the object 
{
   $Duration: 1200,
   $Opacity: 2
}

Comment: If the destination accepts, you need not to parse, but to stringify your string to json object, and pass

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose key/props with `"`. `'` single quotes won't work either. If you have control over generating the string. Modify it as below. If not, you should consider using REGEX.

```js
var a = JSON.parse('{"$Duration":1200,"$Opacity":2}'); 
console.log(a);
```

If the key names are fixed, you can simply replace them in the string. And, end up with a valid JSON:

```js
var str      = "{$Duration:1200,$Opacity:2}",
    validStr = str.replace(/((\$[a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:\:))/g, '"$2":'),
    j        = JSON.parse(validStr);
console.log(j);
```

Comment: The string is the input. Is there easy way to modify the string as mentioned above

Comment: @pankajt, are the keys fixed? if so, yes, I can provide a workaroun

Comment: I don't have a proper solution yet

Comment: I thought of similar approach of using keyObjectMap. I was looking for something easier as I have too many such strings. Thanks for the help

Comment: @pankajt, the updated snippet should work with variety of keys

Comment: This is a good approach. Giving one example of different string 
{$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,$Opacity:$JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear},$Opacity:2}

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply `JSON.stringify()` it and then `JSON.parse()` no need to add extra quotes anywhere.Run below code snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    var str = JSON.stringify({$Duration:1200,$Opacity:2});
    $scope.list = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(JSON.parse(str));

});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  
  {{list}}
  <p>{{list.$Duration}}  - {{list.$Opacity}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: The last bit of line did not give me a JSON object